# How to add a menu along side a sprite sheet level

Tags: java

I am trying to make a game using Java.
I have written a Start Menu Class, which displays the start menu when the program is run and allows the user to navigate a menu using the WASD keys.
I have also developed a Resource Folder, called Res, which contains the game level design called level. 
I originally had the game class extend a JPanel, this allowed a GameMenuManager class to be able the StartMenu to be displayed before the level design. I have changed the level design so that it uses a SpriteSheet to display textures, this involved changing the Game class so it extends Canvas. 
I then tried to add the GameMenuManager back to the Game class:

```
public class Game extends Canvas, JPanel implements Runnable
{
   ...
}
```

Now it displays an error as only one thing can be extended in the Game class:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

    at game.window.Game.main(Game.java:143)
```

This is what is on line 143:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
  new Window(800, 600, "Revision Snake", new Game());
}
```

I don’t know how to display the start menu first and then allow the user to press start and then display the level.

Comment: You should really post more of your code so we can better understand, for starters what is surrounding the line 143 where your error is being reported. Look into [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Do you use any IDE, like Eclipse, Netbeans, IntelliJ and so on?

Comment: reporter - I use Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

You cannot extends more than one class in JAVA!

Take a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html